# Can I use one entity for mulitple datasources in Solr?

Tags: solr, entity

I want to import mutiple sharding databases into one entity in Solr. The sharding databases have the same scheme.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, it should possible. Are you using DataImportHandler (the question does not say)?

Have you already done a DIH import of a single database and want to just have that definition apply to multiple sources?

If so, you have two basic options to go forward:

- Copy the entity definition with appropriately changed sources. When you run DIH, it will execute first entity, then the other
- Create an outer entity with rootEntity = false and with your database entity inside of it. Then, your outer entity needs to generate some sort of variable with each round corresponding to different shard. Your inner entity will use that variable to connect to the correct shard and execute the load. You could , for example, have an XML file with your dataSource names for the outer entity to parse it with XPathEntityProcessor

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I'm using DataImportHandler, does it ok to use different entities, which are actually the same ones in the logic?

Comment: Sure. Just remember that if they are outer entities (scenario 1), each one creates a new entry. If they are nested within the outer entity (with rootEntity=true), the inner entities are just contributing to the same outer entity.